# Cannot deactivate site template (solution) after creating and deleting a new site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site-template

In SharePoint 2010, I created a new site template from an existing site and a new site using this template. After deleting the new site and I cannot deactivate the site template to be able to remove it. Here's the exception I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.get_Item(Guid id) +27763375
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetCachedWeb(SPSite site, Guid webId, Guid featureId) +252

[SPFeatureIsOrphanedException: Unable to access web scoped feature (Id: 5c143ca0-e513-4fa5-93a6-a926352c982e) because it references a non-existent or broken web (Id: 196cdf6e-d4a1-4cb6-b962-591aaa3c5f43) on site 'http://win-9o8m2cks1v7'.  Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.get_Item(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetCachedWeb(SPSite site, Guid webId, Guid featureId)]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetCachedWeb(SPSite site, Guid webId, Guid featureId) +22713369
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetNextFeatureFromRowset(GetFeaturesState state, SqlDataReader reader, SPSite site) +464
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteFeatureEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext() +38
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureQueryResultCollection.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext() +26338677
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.RemoveFeatureInstancesAndDefinition(SPFeatureDefinition featdef) +770
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Remove(SPUserSolution solution) +279
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SolutionItemButton.DeactivateItem() +464
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

I already emptied the recyble bin. Does anybody know how can I deactivate and delete this site template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793911/cannot-deactivate-site-template-solution-after-creating-and-deleting-a-new-sit), all recycle bins need to be emptied before a this type of solution can be deactivated.

Go to `Root Site Settings --> Recycle bin (under Site Collection Administration)` and empty both `End user Recycle Bin items` and `Deleted from end user Recycle Bin`. Afterwards, the solution can be deactivated and removed.